# message sent when a window is shown

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a window object globally and display it only when it is necessary, most of the time window will be in invisible mode. I have some work to do whenever the window is visible. can any one please tell me which message should i override to put the code which is supposed to execute when a window.show method is called?

Comment: it would be helpfull if you add what you have allready tried, what kind of message -> more context pls:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IsVisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx) should do what you want.

```
private void Window_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
  {
     //Do what you need here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Window class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) and also the [Window lifetime cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Window_Lifetime_Events). Now out of this, we can conclude that you (probably) need the [IsVisibleChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx).